# "have a certain kind of air about oneself" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Taken from the book titled "W is for Wasted" by Sue Grafton:

> He had a courtly air about him.

I unfortunately can't seem to find any good explanation anywhere on the web.
I also don't think [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120305221232AANAOUz) is related to the phrase, I'm trying comprehend.

This is a more detailed excerpt from the book:

> He had a courtly air about him. Maybe it was the dress shirt or the hint of humor in his eyes. I thought he seemed surprisingly intelligent, and then I had to stop and correct myself.

Comment: Googling "have an air" works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means he gives the impression of possessing that attribute.  In this case, he gives the impression of being courtly, as though courtliness were emanating from him into the atmosphere.